# React Milti Page Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a multi page app with react routing.

I am have some questions as to how I should structure the routing in the react project.

I want to load my  component in my app.js file. In my Home component I would like to have the ability to press a button which will take me to the Poems component, I want the code to be clean and structured into components, therefore I dont want to do all this in the app.js file.

If someone would explain to me how to best do this I can from there be able to route around to multiple pages afterwards depending on the page you are on. I dont want to have a global menu currently (I will want that in the Poems component later though).

Here is my current App.js file & Home.jsx component code just for a more easily adjustable experience for you guys!

Currently it is not optimized to work so if anyone knows a good routing solution for my issue, please give me an example of the routing fix.

Thanks alot
/Jacob

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.scss'

import { Home, Poems, Favourites } from './Pages'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="app">
                
            <Home />
            
            <Routes> {/* I read that the Switch was replaces with Routes */}
                <Route path="/" exact component={ Home } />
                <Route path="/Poems" component={ Poems } />
                <Route path="/Favourites" component={ Favourites } />
            </Routes>
            </div>

        </Router>
    )
}

export default App
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import { Poems } from './Pages'

import './Home.scss'

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
            <h1>Petry For All</h1>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/Poems" component={ Poems } />
                <Link to="/Poems">Poems</Link>
            </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>

    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Your app only needs one router component to provide a routing context to all routes and links. The `Router` in `home` actually blocks the navigation actions from reaching the root router in `App`, so it doesn't know to rerender a different route. Remove all extraneous routers but the highest one in the ReactTree (*i.e. likely the one here in `App`*).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (and actually shouldn't) duplicate the `<Router>` component in all of the route pages. It is only the root component that is acting as a router. So you can keep the App component the same, and then replace the Home component with the following:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Poems } from './Pages'
import './Home.scss'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Petry For All</h1>
      <Link to="/Poems">Poems</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

The `<Link>` component resolves into an anchor element which, when clicked, navigates the user to the route passed into the `to` property.

Comment: Thanks alot! I will try this out!